# How to filter multiple json items in a json array from onChange event

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, react-select

I have a `react-select` component that I am taking multiple values from. I am then trying to find all matches in a JSON array. I been trying for a while cant figure out the best way. I want to filter and print the matches. Below is the data. i want to get all conditions that match the selected symptoms.

```js
export const symptomsCondition = [
  {
    condition: "Acetaminophen And Nsaid Toxicity",
    symptions: ["Disorganized Speech", "Insomnia"],
  },
  {
    condition: "Acne",
    symptions: ["Swelling (Axilla)", "Bleeding Easily", "Difficult To Wake Up", "Increased Thirst"],
  },
  {
    condition: "Adrenal Disorders (Addison’S Disease And Cushing’S Syndrome",
    symptions: ["Weakness (Leg)", "Tremor", "Premature Ejaculation"],
  },
  {
    condition: "Age Related Cognitive Decline",
    symptions: ["Swelling (Jaw)", "Furry Tongue", "Headache (Worst Ever)", "Mucus In Eyes"],
  },
  {
    condition: "Alcohol: Reducing The Risks",
    symptions: [
      "Pulling Out Eyebrows",
      "Bleeding (Toes)",
      "Craving To Eat Ice",
      "Weakness (Shoulder)",
      "Pounding Heart",
    ],
  },
  {
    condition: "Allergies",
    symptions: ["Thick Saliva", "Unable To Grip (Hands)", "Irregular Heartbeat"],
  },
```

```js
 const [yoursymptoms, setYourSymptoms] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    symptomsCondition.symptoms.find((yoursymptoms) => 
    console.log(yoursymptoms);
    )
  }, [yoursymptoms]);

onChange={setYourSymptoms}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `filter` on your array with the required criterias. Something like:

```js
const allConditions = symptomsConditions.filter(c => c.symptions.includes(yoursymptoms))
```

And if you want only conditions, you can chain this with

```js
.map(c => c.conditon)
```

Comment: thats is great. but what do you mean chain?

Comment: `const allConditions = symptomsConditions.filter(c => c.symptions.includes(yoursymptoms)).map(c => c.conditon)`